# Javascript jQuery: regexp on fieldset

Tags: javascript, ajax, regex

I got a problem with a regexp in javascript so i'm requesting for your help.

So, I got an ajax query result stored in a var (regexp in this case) and I want to match only the content of the fieldset tag.

Here's part of my HTML:

```
<fieldset class="form-wrapper" >
    <form action="/users/login" id="UserLoginForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><div style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" /></div>
        <div class="input text required">
            <label for="UserUsername">Username</label>
            <input name="data[User][username]" type="text" maxlength="255" id="UserUsername" />
        </div>
        <div class="input password">
            <label for="UserPassword">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="data[User][password]" id="UserPassword" />
        </div>  
        <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <p id="user-management-links">
        <a href="/users/forgotten_password">Forgotten password ?</a>        
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="/users/register">Sign up</a>  
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

And here's my regexps :

This one work : `var regexp = content.match(/<form .*?>(.*?)<\/form>/)[0];`

This one not : `var regexed = content.match(/<fieldset>(.*)<\/fieldset>/)[0];`

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
var regexed = content.match(/<fieldset .*?>(.*)<\/fieldset>/)[0];
```

You forgot the .*? from the first one, i think.

EDIT: that would work if javascript would have the option to enable the dot to match also spaces and new lines (reason why probably it is not working for you)

I came up with this:

```
<fieldset .*? >(.|\W)*</fieldset>
```

that works without any options enabled